# PartialViews And Validation (Postback)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, postback, partial-views

The title might not be so clear (because I couldn't find a better one) but what I'm trying to figure out is when you have a normal (as opposed to partial) view, usually there's a GET action method which simply renders the view with a new instance of the view model, and a POST action method (usually with the same name) that accepts an instance of the view model as a parameter. Inside the POST action method, you check the ModelState if it's valid you do what you're supposed to do, if not you render the view again with the same view model instance in order to display any errors.

That's actually one of the things I really like about ASP.NET MVC, but how does that work with Partial Views? If I render back a partial view with the instance of the view model, it only displays the partial view with a white background, out of the context of the whole web application. And if I post back a normal View passing the instance of the view model, that causes a StackOverflowException.

Here's an example:

```
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return PartialView(new LoginViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel dto)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (_userService.AuthenticateUser(dto.Email, dto.Password, false)) {
                var user = _userService.GetUserByEmail(dto.Email);
                var uSession = new UserSession
                {
                    ID = user.Id,
                    Nickname = user.Nickname
                };
                SessionManager.RegisterSession(SessionKeys.User, uSession);
                flag = true;

                if(dto.RememberMe)
                {
                    _appCookies.Email = dto.Email;
                    _appCookies.Password = dto.Password;
                }
            }
        }
        if (flag)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        else
        {
            ViewData.Add("InvalidLogin", "The login info you provided were incorrect.");
            return View(dto); //causes a StackOverflowException
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:** Here's the login view:

```
@inherits ModelWebViewPage<Sharwe.MVC.ViewModels.LoginViewModel>

<div class="userFormHeader"><h2>Login</h2></div>
<div id="loginBox">
    @using(Html.BeginForm("Login", "User", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div id="loginFormFields">
            <div class="display-field">@this.TextBox(m => m.Email).Class("emailField").Attr("rel", "email").Class("autoText")</div>

            <div class="display-field">@this.TextBox(m => m.Password).Class("passwordField").Attr("rel", "password").Class("autoText")</div>

            <div>@this.CheckBox(m => m.RememberMe) <span class="smallText">remember me</span></div>
        </div>

        <div id="loginFormActions">
            <div><input type="submit" id="loginSubmit" class="okButton" name="loginSubmit" value="Ok" /></div>
            <div> @this.Html.ActionLink("forgot password", "ForgotPassword", "User", new { @class = "verySmallText" } )</div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

So how should I do this? Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** *(after Darin's answer)*

Here's how my Login action method now looks like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel dto)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (_userService.AuthenticateUser(dto.Email, dto.Password, false))
            {
                var user = _userService.GetUserByEmail(dto.Email);
                var uSession = new UserSession
                {
                    ID = user.Id,
                    Nickname = user.Nickname
                };
                SessionManager.RegisterSession(SessionKeys.User, uSession);
                flag = true;

                if (dto.RememberMe)
                {
                    //create the authentication ticket
                    var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                        1,
                        user.Id.ToString(), //user id
                        DateTime.Now,
                        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), // expiry
                        true, //true to remember
                        "", //roles 
                        "/"
                        );

                    //encrypt the ticket and add it to a cookie
                    var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                                                FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                }
            }
        }
        if (flag)
        {
            return Json(new { redirectTo = Url.Action("Index", "Home") });
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData.Add("InvalidLogin", "The login info you provided were incorrect.");
            return PartialView(dto);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us the code for Login view

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: Sure. An example would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated in the comments section that AJAX is an option for you here's how you could proceed by AJAXifying the login form. The [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) is excellent for this job and I would strongly recommend it.

So you could provide an id to the login form in the login view:

```
@inherits ModelWebViewPage<Sharwe.MVC.ViewModels.LoginViewModel>
<div class="userFormHeader"><h2>Login</h2></div>
<div id="loginBox">
    @using(Html.BeginForm("Login", "User", null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "loginForm" }))
    {
        ...
    }
</div>
```

and then include a javascript which will AJAxify this form:

```
$(function() {
    ajaxifyLoginForm();
});

function ajaxifyLoginForm() {
    $('#loginForm').ajaxForm({
        success: function(html) {
            $('#loginBox').html(html);
            ajaxifyLoginForm();
        }
    });
}
```

Now all that's left is to return a partial view from the `Login` controller action in case there is an error:

```
return PartialView(dto);
```

We need to handle the success case as well. This could be done by returning a JSON string:

```
return Json(new { redirectTo = Url.Action("Index", "Home") });
```

and then adapt the client script:

```
function ajaxifyLoginForm() {
    $('#loginForm').ajaxForm({
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.redirectTo != null && data.redirectTo != '') {
                // Everything went fine => the user is successfully 
                // authenticated let's redirect him
                window.location.href = data.redirectTo;
            } else {
                // the model state was invalid or the user entered incorrect
                // credentials => refresh the login partial in the DOM and
                // reajaxify the form:
                $('#loginBox').html(data);
                ajaxifyLoginForm();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: unfortunately, that did not work. For some reason, whether the login is valid or not, it loads a copy of the website inside the login form! I've edited my post, see my updated Login action method and let me know if I messed anything up...

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: I figured out the login always fails because I need to set the type to 'POST'. But, I used firebug to check the data being posted and apparently nothing is being posted! Do I need to serialize the values of the text boxes or what?

Comment: @Kassem, no you don't need to serialize them. That's what the jquery form plugin automatically does.

Comment: @Kassem, what do you see in FireBug? Is an AJAX request sent to the `Login` action? What parameters does it contain? What does the server responds?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: I have no idea what is happening... Sometimes it posts nothing to the server (in most cases), sometimes it does and then I get a blank page with {"redirectTo":"/"} and sometimes it just does what I described above...